# Macbook Pro 2019 Catalina wifi very slow while connected through VPN

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, catalina, vpn

I have a MacBook Pro 2019 (with Catalina) from my work/office. I am using a 5 GHz wifi connection for the internet. I have noticed that my personal desktop pc sitting next to my MacBook has an internet speed of about 150 Mbps (download) and 20 Mbps (upload) speed. While MacBook connected through VPN has a download speed of 2.5 Mbps and upload speed of less than 1 Mbps. When I disconnect the Macbook internet speed goes to close to 150 Mbps (download) and about 15-20 Mbps (upload). It is extremely hard to attend MS Team meetings and watch recorded meeting videos. It is also very hard to browse the internet.

I wonder if there is a resolution to this problem?

Comment: Have the 2 computers different IP address ? Does it work better if you disconnect the PC from the network ? I found [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251223376) on Apple forum.

Comment: No. I just tried. The download/upload speed over VPN was 4.12/0.66 Mbps. Then I disconnected VPN and the speed was bumped to 122/11 Mbps. Both while my personal pc was disconnected from the wifi router.

Comment: After connecting back my pc to wifi, pc down/up speed is 182/21.4 Mbps. The MacBook has 91/11 Mbps with VPN and with VPN it is 2.18/0.83 Mbps.